# missing asp.net mvc template after update 4 for Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Tags: visual-studio-2013

i updated vs 2013 this morning. and now I want to add a new controller into the mvc5.0 project. but all templates are gone excep web API ones.[image]

most likely there are related but when I add an action into existing controller, right click menu doesn't have Create View it has only go to view.[image]

is there anyone else having similar problem?  or any idea how to resolve it other than uninstalling update?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you try updating using package manager?   open package manager console and use Update-Package microsoft.aspnet.mvc   and Update-Package microsoft.aspnet.webapi

Comment: I did uninstall the update. and I had similar problem like in my screenshots. I tried to update the mvc I got an error and I tried to install the microsoft.aspnet.mvc and it looks like it is working. one more time i did that after uninstall the update 4. might another time I can try to update one more time and check the packages.